# Why I don't see error exception on the client?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have this action method:

```
    public ActionResult SavePoint(PointRequest point)
    {
        //some logic
        
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Error, no point found");
    }
    
    and this ajax:
    
    function saveFeature(feature, callback, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.homeUrl + "Feature/SavePoint",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: feature,
        success: callback,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);     
            }
        });
    }
```

In save feature function I want to alert text of the exception: 'Error, no point found'.

But thrownError is empty, any idea why in thrownError I dont see error message?

Comment: throwing an exception in the server throws on the server, not the client (browser)

Comment: the answer, generally speaking, is that it is dependent on configuration of ASP.NET, IIS\Owin (essentially your web server stack).  How are you running your app? what kind of build are you doing? what modules are you using for Unhandled Exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Jaromanda X and Brett Caswell answered  the "why" in their comments.  But you can do it like this:

```
    public ActionResult SavePoint(PointRequest point)
    {
        try
        {
            //some logic
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error, no point found");
        }
    }
```

Or, to include the actual error to the user:

```
public ActionResult SavePoint(PointRequest point)
{
    try
    {
        //some logic
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"Error, no point found. Message: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: as helpful as this is; it is a workaround and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question, it shows a valid way to do it - it isn't a workaround.

Comment: right, jdoer.. (to be clear, I didn't\wouldn't downvote for suggesting or including such information).. but the OP is basically providing a scenario of doing an unhandled exception and asking why the response doesn't include the exception message, and your answer suggests handling it.  You should address that inquiry (the question) and also provide this (your example of handling exceptions).

Comment: also, you're right. "workaround" was not the correct term for me to use.  I thought initially this was a pseudo code example to facilitate asking the question, but addressing the 'want'\result was probably the real intent here.